# Comment posted a year before the answer it's associated with

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I recently got a notification about a new comment:

[image: Notification screenshot]

Which implies a comment has just been added. It's a new comment which I'm *certain* I haven't seen before, however the comment itself on the question shows it was added in 2010...

[image: Comment screenshot]

It's definitely the same comment as the [link in the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699008/can-i-create-a-google-account-programmatically/5942303?noredirect=1#comment37609735_5942303) jumps to the correct comment and highlights it.

So... Has the comment been misplaced for years and only just surfaced, has it been added with the wrong date or am I missing something obvious?

I know user error on my part is the obvious reason (not noticing the comment) but I've been back to that answer a couple of times and updated it over the years and would have noticed a comment relating to a potential problem.

Edit 1: As [pointed out by @BradleyDotNET below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261130/comment-posted-a-year-before-the-answer-its-associated-with?cb=1#comment46638_261130), the comment is dated a year before the answer.

Edit 2: [@user2357112 has spotted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261293/1438393) that it's an answer converted to a comment, but I'm still unsure why it's a comment on my answer, not the question. It implies my solution needs email confirmation (which it doesn't) so is a little misleading now.

Comment: Did you happen to set your system clock back 4 years?

Comment: sometimes the conversion from Unicorn Standard Time on the server to your local time in your inbox goes wonky.

Comment: I'm also seeing this lately, but for younger comments (1~2 hours).

Comment: I see a lot of repeat notifications lately. For example, I'll get one new comment but the notification icon and dropdown will show three comments as new - the actual new one, and two old ones (from the last hour or so) that I've already been notified about and acknowledged.

Comment: @jball a) I'm in UTC and b) I've yet to find a timezone that's 4 years out... But I take your point

Comment: @Servy No... But shouldn't this all be server-based anyway? (possibly with some time zone handling in JS)...

Comment: Its pretty impressive that the comment was posted **a full year** before the answer...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I didn't even think to check that. Nicely spotted

Comment: I also received a notification about a comment which was posted on [Oct 10 '09 at 14:17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522207/calculating-roots-with-bc-math-or-gmp?noredirect=1#comment37601884_1522207).

Comment: If only his name was John Titor...

Comment: Wow, this is pretty mystical. Mysticial, where are you?..

Comment: @ComFreek: Same thing. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1548065/1438393) was converted to a comment by Flexo.

Comment: @Servy: Why should a user's local time affect notifications generated by the SO system?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It got converted from an answer to a comment.

[image: Converted answer posted on April 23, 2010]

Comment: Good catch... But then why's it a comment on my answer? It implies that my solution requires email confirmation (which it doesn't)...

Comment: @Basic: My guess would be that Brad Larson wasn't sufficiently familiar with the API to realize that. The answer/now-comment seems to be talking about the ordinary, go-through-Google's-site-in-a-web-browser way of creating an account.

Comment: Ah ok, I hadn't considered that it was a deliberate choice on BradLarson's part. Fair enough. Thanks for working out what was going on.

Comment: +1. Nice detective work!

Comment: @AmalMurali: Eh, it pretty much amounted to scrolling down.