# New notification for old comment

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

I’ve just received a notification for a comment:

[image]

This [refers to a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/57244762?noredirect=1) that is *more than five years old*.

What?

Comment: That's weird the only thing I have noticed is, that you get a new notification, if someone edits their comment when they have your `@username` in it

Comment: @Rizier123 - Sure, but you can only edit your comment a few minutes after you make it. They can't have edited their comment from 5 years ago in the last 16 minutes. The comment doesn't even have a pencil on it indicating it's been edited (like this one is about to).

Comment: There was a report about very old comments appearing as new in the noty-bar, can't find it right now.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The comment id is near 57 millions (`57244762`), which seems to indicate that this comment is new (assuming that comments id are attributed chronologically).  Some comments to the same question also have the same problem.

Using [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4315214%2Fhow-to-learn-to-write-idiomatic-c-code) ([screenshot if it has expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1jOR.png)), we can see that the comment was linked to an old answer which has been converted to a comment lately (guessing it from the "put on hold 6 hours ago").

The fact that you've been re-notified is an [old bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261130/4523901).